# Retrieving SQL Date Datatype from Table with lucene search

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, lucene

I am using the Lucene 3,6,2 as a search engine in my application that 
 uses java derby DB and swing interface and the netbeans IDE.

for now I am able to retrieve all information from the about the query 
 as string datatype.I present the code below.

```
// create some index
        Directory index = new RAMDirectory();
        StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(matchVersion);
        IndexWriterConfig IWConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_36, analyzer);
        IndexWriter iw = new IndexWriter(index,IWConfig) ;

           try {

      con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);

    Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
     String sql = "SELECT * FROM APP.REGISTRY";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

         rs.beforeFirst();
         while(rs.next()) {
         doc = new Document();
         doc.add(new Field("id",rs.getString("ID"),Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED));
         doc.add(new Field("subject",rs.getString("SUBJECT"),Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED));
         doc.add(new Field("letter_from",rs.getString("LETTER_FROM"),Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED));
         doc.add(new Field("date_of_letter",rs.getString("DATE_OF_LETTER"),Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED));        
         doc.add(new Field("date_received",rs.getString("DATE_RECEIVED"),Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED));
```

but there is a date column and I will like to retrieve data from the date column as date data type and not as string datatype.

any suggestion on how to do achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by converting your dates to longs (Date.getTime()), and store them as a [NumericField](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/document/NumericField.html)

```
NumericField letterDateField = new NumericField("date_of_letter",Field.Store.YES,true);
letterDateField.setLongValue(rs.getDate("DATE_OF_LETTER").getTime());
doc.add(letterDateField);
NumericField receivedDateField = new NumericField("date_received",Field.Store.YES,true);
receivedDateField.setLongValue(rs.getDate("DATE_RECEIVED").getTime());
doc.add(receivedDateField);
```

in order to get the time back, simply pull the long value and create a new Date with it:

```
Date letterDate = new Date(doc.getField("date_of_letter").numericValue().longValue());
```

when searching a range, you'll need to convert the values for comparison to longs as well, like:

```
NumericRangeQuery.newLongRange("date_of_letter",minDate.getTime(),maxDate.getTime(),true,false)
```

Alternatively, if necessary, you could store components of the date in separate fields (ie. a year field, a month field, a day field, etc.). This would allow you to design some queries that would be difficult or impossible if storing numeric date values (such as, if you wanted to query anything with a date in February, in any year).

Personally, I would recommend against using [NumericUtils](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/util/NumericUtils.html) directly.

Comment: why will you recommend against using NumericUtils directly

Comment: @femtorogon Just tried your suggestion but lucene tells me that NumericField does not accept a long data type generated by the getTime() method but it rather it takes an int data type.  any further suggestions

Comment: Lucene's NumericUtils is intended for internal use, as noted in it's documentation.  It's API can and has changed (non backwards-compliant as of 4.0).  Transforming to and from prefixcoded makes assumptions about Lucene's internal storage requirements that would be better left to Lucene to figure out.

Comment: Forgot the NumericField ctor doesn't take a value (can take an int as the second arg, but that's a precision step, not a value).  That is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`NumericField`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_2/api/all/org/apache/lucene/document/NumericField.html). With numeric fields, you will be able to do range queries (which behave completely different if the data type is `String`).

You can convert your date into a timestamp using static `NumericUtils.longToPrefixCoded` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a better method of indexing dates, using [DateTools](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/DateTools.html?is-external=true).

Using it to convert dates to a string will allow searching both as either a (lexicographic, rather than numeric) range, or searching individual terms.  Take a look at the [QueryParser documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParser.html) for how it handles date ranges.

You can add your date values to the index like:

```
doc.add(new Field("date_of_letter",DateTools.dateToString(rs.getDate("DATE_RECEIVED"),DateTools.Resolution.DAY),Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED));        
doc.add(new Field("date_received",DateTools.dateToString(rs.getDate("DATE_RECEIVED"),DateTools.Resolution.DAY),Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED));
```

And convert values back to dates similarly with

```
DateTools.stringToTime(dateResult);
```

Comment: thanks , will also have a look at that and get back to you. But does mean that dateutil cannot be used for range search

Comment: which vrsion of lucene are you sing looks like DateUtil in lucene 3.6.2 , the version I am using has no method like datetostring(). because the Netbeans IDE is complaining about the method

Comment: @faisalabdulai I got crossed up a bit between `DateTools` and `NumericUtils` to come up with `DateUtils`.  You're looking for `DateTools`.